# Syntax for release-strategy-expression in spring integration

Tags: spring, integration, spring-el

Here is the code snippet of what is expected:

```
<int:resequencer input-channel="resequencerChannel" output-channel="headerRoutingChannel"
       send-timeout="10000" release-strategy-expression="size() eq (T(java.lang.Runtime).getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 3)"/>
```

But the syntax seems to be incorrect. I would like to know the actual syntax for the release-strategy-expression. 
Thanks in advance.

```
Stack Trace:
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E:(pos 8): Type cannot be found 'org.springframework.util.Assert'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeLocator.findType(StandardTypeLocator.java:115)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ExpressionState.findType(ExpressionState.java:138)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.TypeReference.getValueInternal(TypeReference.java:58)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:48)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Ternary.getValueInternal(Ternary.java:57)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getArguments(MethodReference.java:147)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueRef(MethodReference.java:66)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:63)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:111)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:268)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:73)
```

Comment: Provide more info, please, what you want to achieve. You SpEL is really incorrect now

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to release when the group size reaches 3x the available processors...

`size() eq ...` ?

Comment: I tried testing the expression using SpelExpressionParser and it evaluates the expression as expected. However from xml config, I get following exception: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E:(pos 8): Type cannot be found 'org.springframework.util.Assert'

Comment: I just tested it (copied your configuration from above) and it worked fine for me (also with ==). I put a breakpoint in `OpEQ` and `left` evaluated to 1 (first message) and `right` evaluated to 12 on my laptop. Worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you try it using XML config or through SpelExpressionParser explicitly?